# Rsync between KVM VPS and VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, rsync, vps

I need advice how to rsync via ssh (and what directories need to be synced) between a KVM VPS (Debian Jessie) and VirtualBox to effectively make the VirtualBox a clone of the VPS. I use the term "clone" loosely because what I REALLY need is for it to sync

- Libraries
- Programs (and all their dependencies)
- Program Settings
- Users
- User Settings
- User Files
- Permissions (attached to files)
- Other ??

Basically I need a way to sync where if I install Program A on VPS, after the sync I want Program A to run perfectly fine on the VirtualBox... It doesn't need to sync any network info as the gateway etc will be different on the VBox.

For example, let's say on the VPS, I install a firewall and configure it to block port 22 (this would be horrible because ssh would stop, but just suppose). I'd like after the sync for the firewall to be installed on the VBox machine with the firewall settings intact.

I'm doing this because I would like a way to experiment with new libraries and extensions and programs on the VirtualBox machine before uploading or changing these settings on the VPS. But my knowledge is lacking as to which directories are needed to sync and which are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do a base install in a virtualbox VM, then use `apt-clone` to copy the packages and package system state of the existing system into the VM. That will help when testing upgrades etc.

All configuration as far as Debian is concerned is in `/etc/`. Home directories of course are under `/home/`.

Comment: What about libraries? Where are libraries and dependencies for programs stored?... The ("AppData" and "Program Files" of linux) or is that all in /home and /etc too?